# Save value from sub query and reuse it later?

Tags: postgresql

How do I use the result of a sub query multiple times? Is there any way to name that result and use it somewhere else? I know about with xyz as ... and that doesn't seem to work?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766657/how-do-you-use-variables-in-a-simple-postgresql-script) and would like something more specific?

Sample of broken code:

```
with g_surf as (select surface_area from countries where name like 'Germa%')
select abs(surface_area - g_surf) from countries;
```

working code that uses the entire sub query:

```
select abs(surface_area - (select surface_area from
    countries where name like 'Germa%')) from countries;
```

Comment: It is called CTE (common table expression). Maybe if you post your try, we can tell why you didn't manage to do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL table variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10785767/postgresql-table-variable)

Comment: You've been a member long enough to know that we're going to need more right? Code, attempts, errors, etc. Also, if you link something, include/quote the important bits so when the link dies, the question doesn't. - edit: and possibly use [pg_fetch_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-fetch-all.php) and save subquery results as stand-alone query?

Comment: @rkeet Is this ok?

Comment: g_surf is the CTE, i.e. it acts as if it is a table, not a field. Therefore: `with g_surf as (select surface_area from countries where name like 'Germa%')
select abs(surface_area) from g_surf;` Of course, if you have a g_surf field in your `countries` table, you can write `with myCTE as (select surface_area, g_surf  from countries where name like 'Germa%')
select abs(surface_area - g_surf) from myCTE;`

Answer (score 1):

Just to mark the question as solved:
`g_surf`, in your example, is the CTE (Common **Table** Expression), i.e. it acts as a table, not as a field.

```
with g_surf as (select surface_area from countries where name like 'Germa%')
select abs(surface_area) from g_surf;
```

Of course, if you have a `g_surf` field in your `countries` table, you can write:

```
with myCTE as (select surface_area, g_surf from countries where name like 'Germa%')
select abs(surface_area - g_surf) from myCTE;
```

More about CTE [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html).

Comment: Thanks a ton. I will check this out soon.

Comment: Wait, in your first example, there is no subtraction? (so does it really do what I set out to do)
Now in your second example, how does surface_area knows it's from countries and g_surf knows its from myCTE?

Comment: It is because your broken code was a bit strange ... When you write `with g_surf as (select surface_area from countries where name like 'Germa%')`, you are very roughly saying: Create a temporary table called `g_surf` whose only field is `surface_area` (no `g_surf` column). However, the part `select abs(surface_area - g_surf) from countries` suggested `g_surf` is a column identifier in table `countries`. I just did not know what assumption was right. If the second query works, I guess that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Well, I'll explain then. The "working code" sample is the one I'm aiming for. I want select, order by and also use where on the difference in surface area and I want to write the sub-query only one time. I will check out your code today. Thanks for helping!